# copy partial file powershell

Tags: powershell, copy

i am trying to copy a part of a source exe file to new dst file,
i use the following commnads:

```
$file = (Get-Content src.exe)[31..111] | Set-Content dst.exe
```

but on the output file i get extra newline symbols which cause an error when i try to run the file.
how do i copy the internal part of the file without damaging it.

i attached a jpg of the dif.
please help

[image]

Comment: You miss the -Encoding Byte as parameter of your Get-Content call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = (Get-Content src.exe -encoding byte)[31..111] | Set-Content dst.exe -encoding byte
```

Comment: This command works great for smaller input files, but on larger files it seems to hang. Something odd is going on as PowerShell had >5GB memory usage when I decided to force kill it via task manager, for a 29MB input file... Any ideas what's going on?